# Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:evernet.nwmls.com/evernetqueryservice/evernetquery.asmx?WSDL:

Tags: php, wsdl, xsd, element, rets

I am trying to do get a response from NWMLS web service using PHP with XML query parsing as in below source code which returns as beneath the error. There are similar questions in SO but those solutions doesn't worked out for me. **How to resolve this?**

Source Code:

```
<?php
try {
$soap_client = new SoapClient('http://evernet.nwmls.com/evernetqueryservice/evernetquery.asmx?WSDL');

$query =  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>";
$query .= "<EverNetQuerySpecification xmlns='urn:evernet.nwmls.com/evernetqueryservice/evernetquery.asmx?WSDL'>";
$query .= "<Message>";
$query .= "<Head>";
$query .= "<UserId>username</UserId>";
$query .= "<Password>password</Password>";
$query .= "<SchemaName>StandardXML1_1</SchemaName>";
$query .= "</Head>";
$query .= "<Body>";
$query .= "<Query>";
$query .= "<MLS>nwmls</MLS>";
$query .= "<PropertyType>MANU</PropertyType>";
$query .= "<BeginDate>2013-10-24T23:00:19</BeginDate>";
$query .= "<EndDate>2013-10-24T23:19:17</EndDate>";
$query .= "<Status>SFR</Status>";
$query .= "</Query>";
$query .= "<Filter></Filter>";
$query .= "</Body>";
$query .= "</Message>";
$query .= "</EverNetQuerySpecification>";



// RetrieveListingData
$params = array('v_strXmlQuery' => $query); // ?
$listing = $soap_client->RetrieveListingData($params);

// RetrieveListingDataResponse
$result = $listing->RetrieveListingDataResult;
echo $result;
// Convert the $result into a multi-dimensional
// array comprising of each returned value
$xml_result = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
// print_r($xml_result->Residential);

$residential = $xml_result->Residential;

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($residential);
echo '</pre>';

exit();

foreach($residential[0] as $tag => $val) {
echo '<p id="'. $tag . '">' . $val . '</p>';
}

// VIEW the wsdl. 
// Uncomment these to see all available methods of the EverNet Service.
/*
var_dump( $soapclient->__getFunctions() );
var_dump( $soapclient->__getTypes() );
*/
} catch (SoapClient $exception) {

echo '<pre>';
echo $exception->getMessage();
echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

Instead of listing I am facing the below issue,

ERROR:

`**Could not find schema information for the element 'urn:evernet.nwmls.com/evernetqueryservice/evernetquery.asmx?WSDL:**` for `EverNetQuerySpecification, Message, Head, UserId, Password, SchemaName, Body, Query, MLS, PropertyType, BeginDate, EndDate, Status, Filter`

Comment: Please post properly formatted code, what you've posted is totally unreadable. Use the `{}` tool to mark code, not the quotation tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s.no Check lists
1. extension=php_openssl.dll - Enabled
2. default_socket_timeout - 60
3. allow_url_fopen - On
4. local cert try this ...
5. www in URL - Present
6. WSDL - Enabled
7. soap.wsdl_cache_enabled - 1
8. The httpd.conf - time out - 600 (very important)

These are the configuration combination, I tried and resolved from 'localhost' wamp not from live server. In addition to get a output value, in included the below,

```
$query .= " <ListingNumber>Your listing ID comes here</ListingNumber>";
```